# How to create a NetCDF mesh with x y vector data for QGIS mesh display

Tags: qgis, netcdf, mesh

I have created a NetCDF mesh with u and v variables for velocity. I can load it onto QGIS 3.14 as a mesh layer. The variables are not recognized as vector though (isVector : No is displayer in group metadata) so I'm unable to display arrows, streamlines etc. I have created the .nc file with NetCDF4-python. The properties of my metadata are:

```
{'time': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time(time)
    axis: T
    standard_name: time
    time_origin: 18-MAR-2020 00:00:00
    units: seconds since 2020-03-18T00:00:00
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (101,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'lat': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 lat(lat)
    axis: Y
    units: degrees_north
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (330,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'lon': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 lon(lon)
    axis: X
    units: degrees_east
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (305,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'u': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 u(time, lat, lon)
    long_name: u_velocity component
    standard_name: eastward_flood_water_velocity
    units: meter second-1
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (101, 330, 305)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'v': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 v(time, lat, lon)
    long_name: v_velocity component
    standard_name: northward_flood_water_velocity
    units: meter second-1
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (101, 330, 305)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used}
```

I have downloaded another .nc dataset I found on this blog https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/10/10/wind-vector-mapping-and-animation-in-qgis and funnily enough I can display arrows on it. The properties for this .nc file is:

```
{'time': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time(time)
    _CoordinateAxisType: Time
    actual_range: [1.6015104e+09 1.6020288e+09]
    axis: T
    calendar: proleptic_gregorian
    ioos_category: Time
    long_name: Forecast time for ForecastModelRunCollection
    missing_value: nan
    standard_name: time
    time_origin: 01-JAN-1970 00:00:00
    units: seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (49,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'depth': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 depth(depth)
    _CoordinateAxisType: Height
    _CoordinateZisPositive: down
    actual_range: [10. 10.]
    axis: Z
    ioos_category: Location
    long_name: Depth
    positive: down
    standard_name: depth
    units: m
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (1,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'latitude': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 latitude(latitude)
    _CoordinateAxisType: Lat
    actual_range: [18.167128 23.049076]
    axis: Y
    ioos_category: Location
    long_name: Latitude
    standard_name: latitude
    units: degrees_north
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (137,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'longitude': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 longitude(longitude)
    _CoordinateAxisType: Lon
    actual_range: [-159.0599  -154.17369]
    axis: X
    ioos_category: Location
    long_name: Longitude
    standard_name: longitude
    units: degrees_east
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (128,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used, 'temp': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 temp(time, depth, latitude, longitude)
    _FillValue: nan
    colorBarMaximum: 27.0
    colorBarMinimum: 23.0
    coordinates: time_run time depth lat lon
    ioos_category: Temperature
    long_name: potential temperature
    missing_value: nan
    standard_name: sea_water_potential_temperature
    units: Celsius
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (49, 1, 137, 128)
filling on, 'salt': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 salt(time, depth, latitude, longitude)
    _FillValue: nan
    colorBarMaximum: 36.0
    colorBarMinimum: 33.0
    coordinates: time_run time depth lat lon
    ioos_category: Salinity
    long_name: salinity
    missing_value: nan
    standard_name: sea_water_salinity
    units: 1e-3
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (49, 1, 137, 128)
filling on, 'u': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 u(time, depth, latitude, longitude)
    _FillValue: nan
    colorBarMaximum: 0.15
    colorBarMinimum: -0.15
    coordinates: time_run time depth lat lon
    ioos_category: Currents
    long_name: u-velocity component
    missing_value: nan
    standard_name: eastward_sea_water_velocity
    units: meter second-1
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (49, 1, 137, 128)
filling on, 'v': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 v(time, depth, latitude, longitude)
    _FillValue: nan
    colorBarMaximum: 0.15
    colorBarMinimum: -0.15
    coordinates: time_run time depth lat lon
    ioos_category: Currents
    long_name: v-velocity component
    missing_value: nan
    standard_name: northward_sea_water_velocity
    units: meter second-1
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (49, 1, 137, 128)
filling on}
```

Here they use an extra dimension called depth. I don't really need that though. I would also like to know which variable attributes are important if at all.

I saw a similar question to this posted before on [Create a flow vector NetCDF from X and Y velocity components](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364832/create-a-flow-vector-netcdf-from-x-and-y-velocity-components). Apparently the question was answered on chat but I can't see the answer.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The long name attributes u_velocity component and y_velocity component had to be changed to u-velocity component and v-velocity component respectively.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS uses [MDAL](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL) library for reading the NetCDF data. Depending of MDAL driver that is used, there is a hardcoded logic how to determine is dataset is vector or not. For example for [NetCDF GDAL driver](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL/blob/5e8223ed283c15815089bcf7e5558e4b5660ac88/mdal/frmts/mdal_gdal.cpp#L644) or for [UGRID NetCDF](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL/blob/5e8223ed283c15815089bcf7e5558e4b5660ac88/mdal/frmts/mdal_ugrid.cpp#L507). So you need to use for example `u-velocity component` and `v-velocity component` for long name.